# after effects does'nt open

Tags: after-effects

I have a Mac and for the last 24 hours my after effects just does'nt even open. I click on the software and its not responding at all. the only after effects thing that I have on my computer that opens is the render engine but it dose'nt really do much.

Comment: Hi - please can you add what Mac you have, what version of MacOS, version of After Effects, and anything else that might be useful?

Comment: Check if there are crash logs and tell us what they say: https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects/faq-how-to-find-after-effects-crash-logs-on-your-computer/m-p/10333124 (Maybe the logs' location has changed slightly for newer versions.)